# how to two active bootstrap accordion on page load

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have two sets of JQuery Accordions within a single DIV tag.i want to show two Accordions activate. is this possible? 
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTExK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the data-parent attribute.

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<h2>Multiple Slides:</h2>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Group #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
          Group #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          Group #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```